# How to share single instance of Android driver among stepDefinition files

Tags: cucumber, appium

I have two feature files and each feature file have one stepDefinition. Currently working on android automation testing using appium, cucumber and testNG.
Is there any way to share the instance of driver among stepDefinition files.

I used dependency Injection using cucumber pico-container but still it unable to inject the driver instance, getting NullPointer Exception.